# "Next Song" function key (Mac) on Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, mac

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my iMac 2011. I want to use the function keys on the keyboard to skip to the next song, but I get this splash when I press the key:

[image]

Can you help me?